# how to filter the data by colors in excel sheet by using java

Tags: java

I have tried with below code its executing but it is not filtering with colour, After executing highlighted colors are missing

```
public static void filteringLatestMakeModel(String testdatapath, String schemeName,String clientName) throws Exception {

    FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File(testdatapath + FILE_SEPERATOR + schemeName + FILE_SEPERATOR + clientName + FILE_SEPERATOR +"Test data"+FILE_SEPERATOR +"Latest- Make Model Table" + ".xlsx"));    
    XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
    XSSFSheet my_sheet = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheet("D2 - FPUK Upload"); 
    CTAutoFilter sheetFilter=my_sheet.getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter();     

    /* Step -2: Create Filter Column Object and Define Column ID */
    CTFilterColumn  myFilterColumn=sheetFilter.insertNewFilterColumn(0);        
    myFilterColumn.setColId(0L);

    /* Step-3: Create a Color Filter and set ID */  
    CTColorFilter colorFilter=myFilterColumn.addNewColorFilter();
    colorFilter.setDxfId(0L);   

    /* Step-4: Update StyleSheet and Attach Filter Color Details */     
    CTStylesheet wbStyle=my_xlsx_workbook.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet();
    CTDxfs dxSet=wbStyle.addNewDxfs();
    dxSet.setCount(0L);
    CTPatternFill myFill=dxSet.addNewDxf().addNewFill().addNewPatternFill();
    myFill.setPatternType(STPatternType.SOLID);
    CTColor fgColor=myFill.addNewFgColor();
    CTColor bgColor=myFill.addNewBgColor();     
    byte[] fg=javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("FFFFFF00");  // Foreground filter color = green  
    byte[] bg=javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("FFFFFFFF"); // background filter color="white"
    fgColor.setRgb(fg);
    bgColor.setRgb(bg);

    /* Step-5: Refresh Records to Match Filter Condition */
    XSSFRow r1;     
    /* Step-6: Loop through Rows and Apply Filter */
    for(Row r : my_sheet) {
        for (Cell c : r) {
            //if foreground filter color is not green then hide the record
            if ( c.getColumnIndex()==1  && c.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor() !=17){
                r1=(XSSFRow) c.getRow();
                if (r1.getRowNum()!=0) { /* Ignore top row */
                /* Hide Row that does not meet Filter Criteria */
                    r1.getCTRow().setHidden(true); }
            }               
        }
    }       
    /* Step-7: Write changes to the workbook */
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(testdatapath + FILE_SEPERATOR + schemeName + FILE_SEPERATOR + clientName + FILE_SEPERATOR +"Test data"+FILE_SEPERATOR +"Latest- Make Model Table" + ".xlsx"));
    my_xlsx_workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
}
```

this is the code with I have tried

Comment: From where does 17 come from? Can you post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: 17 is the value of green colour